# Why rails engine (3.2.12) wants to mass_assign field which is not on the form new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

In our `rails 3.2.12 engine`, there is a `model misc_definition`. Here is a line in the misc_definition model:

```
attr_accessible :brief_note, :for_which, :name, :ranking_order, :as => :role_new
```

The form for creating new misc_definition is:

```
<%= simple_form_for @misc_definition do |f| %>     
  <%= f.input :name, :label => name_label %>
  <%= f.input :brief_note, :label => "Brief Note:", :input_html => {:rows => 2} %> 
  <%= f.input :for_which, :input_html => {:value => @for_which}, :as => :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :ranking_order, :label => 'Ranking Index', :placehoder => '1, 2, 3 ...'%> 
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Save' %>  
<% end %>
```

There is no `active` in the form above for new misc_definition. The error in `rspec` is:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error←[0m:
       ←[31mCan't mass-assign protected attributes: active←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/projectx/misc_definitions_controller.rb:29:in `new'←[0m
```

line 29 in controller is:

```
@misc_definition = Projectx::MiscDefinition.new(params[:misc_definition], :as => :role_new)
```

The error disappears when adding `active` to `:role_new's` `attr_accessible` list untill every field is added to the `attr_accessible` list. However in regular rails app, there is no problem if the field is not in the list of `attr_accessible`, rails app just skips assigning any value to the field. However in rails engine, it throws out `mass_assignment` error for any field which is not on the form new.

Is there someone having the idea about the mass_assign error in `rails engine`? Is it a bug in `rails engine`? Thanks.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be related to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9456), would it?

Comment: It is the same issue. We initially reported under rails issue. Now the same problem happen again(never been solved). We want to see if anyone else has had the same issue.